# ¿Como mostrar el texto de un input en un texto en pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Estoy haciendo un editor de pagina web, osea que el dueño de la pagina pueda editar los texto dentro de la pagina sin necesidad de entrar al archivo html, para esto esto poniendo una imagen de demostracion para que vea como se veria en la version publicada.

[image: Imagen de referencia]

Mi pregunta es ¿Como hago para mostrar el texto conforme el dueño escribe una letra? osea que sea automatico y que no tenga que dar clic en un boton para ver como queda.

PD: La imagen solo es el fondo, el div blanco y el texto si esta en el codigo, la unica imagen es el fondo (La calculadora y las hojas de contaduria).

```css
.dashboard_editor{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dashboard_editor #title_dashboard{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: SourceSan_ExtraLight;
    font-size: 34px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.dashboard_content{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.dashboard_content #title_chang_txt_notify{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: SourceSan_ExtraLight;
    font-size: 34px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.box_txt{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -20px 20px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -20px 20px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -20px 20px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.box_txt p{
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Roboto_slab;
    text-align: start;
    color: #000000;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.dashboard_content img{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.dashboard_content #txt_notificacion{
    width: 80%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard_editor">

            <p id="title_dashboard">Editor de Pagina</p>

            <div class="dashboard_content">

                <p id="title_chang_txt_notify">Texto de Notificacion</p>  

                <div class="box_txt">

                    <p>Te ayudamos a presentar tu declaración anual para personas físicas. </br> Regímenes: Asalariado,
                        Arrendamiento, Honorarios, Actividades profesionales y empresariales.</p>

                </div>
                
                <img src="./css/img/img_txt_notification.jpg" alt="Texto de referencia">

                <input type="text" name="txt_notificacion" id="txt_notificacion" placeholder="Cambia el texto de notificacion">

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Publicá el código de lo que intentaste hacer así te podemos ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar el contenido o estructura de una pagina o archivo HTML lo debes hacer usando BD para almacenar los cambios, sin embargo para eso que dices lo puedes hacer desde un input o desde un text area o incluso desde un edittext con plugins, la idea es la misma para los tres

```js
function updateText(e){
  let parrafo = document.querySelector("#parrafo");
  parrafo.innerHTML = e;
}
```

```html
<p id="parrafo"></p>
<input type="text"  onkeyup="updateText(this.value)">
```

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que buscaba, no hay alguna otra manera de cambiar el texto sin BD como por javaScript, como especificar en el codigo js que los cambios se haran en una etiqueta #parrafo en el documento index?

Comment: Si quieres que sean perpetuos no, ya que html se renderiza cada que se abre, por eso se busca la informacion en las BD Para saber que informacion va en que parte

Comment: ok, gracias pues buscare como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que estás usando jquery. Y supongamos que tenés un div y un input así:

```
<div id="texto_a_publicar"></div>
```

....

```
<input type="text" id="texto" />
```

Entonces: con jquery, bastaría esto:

```
$("#texto").on("keyup change input",function(){
     $("#texto_a_publicar").html($(this).val());
});
```

Por ejemplo esto: https://jsfiddle.net/L6cvnjoz/